# Place button to the right of a table cell, but keep it on the same line

Tags: html, html-table, tablecell

I have a table of email addresses and 6 checkboxes on the same line. I need to have the button to edit the email address be on the same line as it. Currently it's in the same cell as the email address. Would it be better for the edit button to have it's own cell? Or is there a style option that would work? Thanks for your help and have a great day.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0g5eax7t/

```
<tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: @Html.Raw(width + "px;") min-width:@Html.Raw(width + "px;")">
      <span id="emailAlertOwnerlabel"></span><b> - Owner</b>
      <input type="button" value="Edit" id="editOwnerEmailAlert" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-default btn-block-mobile btn-xs" tabindex="135">-->
   </td>
    <td class="text-center" style="width: @Html.Raw(width + "px;") min-width:@Html.Raw(width + "px;")" text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-1 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="15" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: @Html.Raw(width + "px;") min-width:@Html.Raw(width + "px;")">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-2 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="16" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: @Html.Raw(width + "px;") min-width:@Html.Raw(width + "px;")">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-3 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="17" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: @Html.Raw(width + "px;") min-width:@Html.Raw(width + "px;")">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-4 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="18" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: @Html.Raw(width + "px;") min-width:@Html.Raw(width + "px;")">
    <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-5 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="19" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: @Html.Raw(width + "px;") min-width:@Html.Raw(width + "px;")">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-6 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="20" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: @Html.Raw(width + "px;") min-width:@Html.Raw(width + "px;")">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sub-col-7 dont-get-data" data-billaccount="emailField" data-subtype="21" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to its own cell like this. If this helped click answer.

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 145px; min-width:145px;">
    <span id="emailAlertOwnerlabel">b@b.com</span><b> - Owner</b>
    </td>
    <!-- <td> insert button here </td> -->
    <td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="editOwnerEmailAlert" style="" class="btn <btn->      </btn->default btn-block-mobile btn-xs" tabindex="135">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- inside its own <td> -->
```

Comment: Thanks @Zapp, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help:

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 145px; min-width:145px;">
    <span  id="emailAlertOwnerlabel">b@b.com</span><b> - Owner</b>
    <input type="button" value="Edit" id="editOwnerEmailAlert" style="position:relative;" class="btn <btn->      </btn->default btn-block-mobile btn-xs" tabindex="135">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```